How to Detect Memory Leaks in .NET MAUI App on iOS Simulator?
I am working on a .NET MAUI application and I suspect that there might be a memory leak in the app when running on the iOS simulator.
Is there a recommended tool or approach to identify which objects are causing the memory leak? I need a way to effectively detect and analyze memory usage to pinpoint the source of the leak.
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
I am working on a .NET MAUI application and I suspect that there might be a memory leak in the app when running on the iOS simulator.
What I have tried so far:
3. Manual Code Review: I reviewed my code for obvious memory management issues, but I couldn't identify any major problems.
What I am expecting:

A recommended tool or method specifically suited for detecting memory leaks in .NET MAUI apps running on the iOS simulator.
Guidance on how to effectively use these tools or approaches to identify which objects are causing the memory leak.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You may follow the steps in Profiling in .NET to profile the app on ios simulator  or on a device

Hi @LiqunShen-MSFT,
I have followed the steps, but I'm encountering an issue where no profile or providers are specified, and it defaults to the trace profile 'cpu-sampling'. Here are the details:
Provider Name: Microsoft-DotNETCore-SampleProfiler
Keywords: 0x0000F00000000000
Level: Informational(4)
Enabled By: --profile
Provider Name: Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime
Keywords: 0x0000014C14FCCBD
Level: Informational(4)
Enabled By: --profile

Additionally, it says:
Waiting for connection on /Users/bharathiselvam/my-sim-port
Start an application with the following environment variable: DOTNET_DiagnosticPorts=/Users/bharathiselvam/my-sim-port

Which command causes the issue?

this command = > $ dotnet-trace collect --diagnostic-port ~/my-sim-port --format speedscope

Does the ios simulator launch correctly?

yes, app launched correctly in the simulator

That's weird. I created a default MAUI project for debugging but it didn't throw any exception.

Could you please explain what should happen after the 4th step if everything works correctly?

It will generate a .nettrace file and a json file to be analyzed. dotnet-trace collect

Hi, are there any other tools available for detecting memory leaks in the iOS simulator? Also, if there's a video tutorial that explains the steps outlined in the Xamarin Profiling guide, it would be very helpful.

Avoid profiling an app in a simulator, as the simulator may distort the app performance.. See Use a profiler

Is there any other tool or instruments to detect memory leaks in iOS simulator ?

Have you tried using this nuget package.
https://github.com/AdamEssenmacher/MemoryToolkit.Maui
The author has explained how to use it. Additionally there is this wiki
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Memory-Leaks

yes , i have tried it , is there any other way to find the memory leak objects of .net maui app using Xcode instruments
